# How do I change a value in multiple arrays if I know the key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with data.
var_damp like this

```
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attribute_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attribute_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attribute_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attribute_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attribute_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
```

How do I change all the values in the arrays in order.
All values ["first_attribute"] => "attribute_1"
must be changed to attr_1, attr_2, attr_3 and so on in order of output.
how to do it?
at the end it should look like this.

```
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attr_1"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attr_2"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attr_3"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attr_4"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
array(2) {
  ["first_attribute"]=>  string(10) "attr_5"
  ["second_attribute"]=>  string(10) "value"
}
```

how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a foreach statement over the array with the following:

```
        // Init the array
        $array = array(
            array(
                "first_attribute"=> "attribute_1",
                "second_attribute"=> "value"
            ),array(
                "first_attribute"=> "attribute_1",
                "second_attribute"=> "value"
            )
        );

        echo "FIRST DUMP:";
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($array);
        echo "</pre>";
  
        // Init $i
        $i = 0;
        
        // Loop through each array
        foreach($array as $row) {
        
            $x = $i + 1;
            $array[$i]["first_attribute"] = "attr_" . $x;
            $i++;
            
        }
        
        echo "SECOND DUMP(AFTER MODIFICATION):";
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($array);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Here is what I am seeing as an output in my browser:

[image: Browser outpur]

Comment: the topmost dump gives this code. $parent_attributes = $product->get_parent_attributes();
How do I need to change it?
I tried changing it this way, $parent_attributes = [$product->get_parent_attributes()]; but it didn't work.

Comment: Right. Did you notice the bottom of my answer where it goes through a foreach array? I believe that will give you the result you are looking for. I edited to show where you should do a var_dump to see the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Here is the dump.

Comment: (array) [1 element]
0: 
(array) [2 elements]
first_attribute: (string) "attr_1"
second_attribute: (string) "value"
(array) [1 element]
0: 
(array) [2 elements]
first_attribute: (string) "attr_1"
second_attribute: (string) "value"
(array) [1 element]
0: 
(array) [2 elements]
first_attribute: (string) "attr_1"
second_attribute: (string) "value"
(array) [1 element]
0: 
(array) [2 elements]
first_attribute: (string) "attr_1"
second_attribute: (string) "value"
(array) [1 element]
0: 
(array) [2 elements]
first_attribute: (string) "attr_1"
second_attribute: (string) "value"

Comment: Can you post some more complete code so I can better help? Hard to go off what I'm seeing.

Comment: Can you confirm the output of the top is not looping through and var_dump on each array? I have updated my code to be more complete for you.

Comment: this is a simple code that takes the default attributes of a product in wordpress. all I want is to take these attributes and put them to product variations.
 this code $parent_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();
gives the same result as on my first dump.
it's already looped and it depends on the number of variations of the product.
Then I do what you wrote but it doesn't work. @bmckay

Comment: Right. But as you can see, the output on my screen is showing exactly what you are wanting, so for me to help more, I need to see more of the code. Can you show more code so I can help?